# How can I change the log directory for JRebel?

Tags: java, jrebel

JRebel is writing a log file to 
 `{user.home}/.jrebel`

How can I change this location, or the value of `{user.home}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the log file location by setting `rebel.log.file=...` in `~/.jrebel/jrebel.properties`

A `JREBEL_HOME` environment variable can be set to change the value of `{user.home}`

Comment: you can also pass -Drebel.log.file=... as a VM argument.